# How do I get path to /data/data folder android

Tags: epub, internal-storage

I have some `epub` files that I saved to android internal storage. I have been using [folioReader](https://github.com/FolioReader/FolioReader-Android) library to display this files but it keeps telling me the path destination is null.

So, I checked android studio's `Device File Explorer` and I found the files this location: `/data/data/packageName/files/FileName`

Am using this code to get path:

```
try{
            String path = getFilesDir().getPath() + "/" + fileName
            folioReader.openBook(path);
                Log.i("Path:", path);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

It returns this path on my `log cat:`

```
/data/user/0/packageName/files/fileName
```

There seems to be a difference in the locations paths.

So, my question is this: how do I get path to this location?

```
/data/data/packageName/files/FileName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private String getFilePath(){
    ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    File filePath = contextWrapper.getFilesDir();
    File file = new File(filePath,"fileName" +"*/*");
    return file.getPath();
}
```

here 'filePath' contains '/data/data/packageName/files/' location
then joining it with '/fileName' gives the whole storage path of that file

*/ * tells that 'fileName' can be of any file type

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it